# AWS IAM - How to provide access to billing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

As a AWS account root user, created an admin user following these [steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/getting-started_create-admin-group.html).

After logging in with admin user, giving admin user_name & password as input

admin user could not get access to account details, as shown below:

[image]
How can a root user give permissions to admin user to view account details?

Answer (score 2):

This is not enabled by default, by default only the root user can see this info, if you look at this tutorial it will help:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_billing.html

It shows the enablement of Billing dashboard etc. for IAM users.